# How to add up totals using php?

Tags: php, html

been trying out my new skills in php to build an accounts style system, that logs incoming and out going payments similar to what you would do in excel. thought this would be a good starting point to test my stills.

now ive built a form which submits to a database, and also a page that allows you to view the payments logged via date.

stuck on getting it to display a profit total. This will be worked out from the incoming payments total minus the outgoing payments totals.

ive attached my code below, id really appreciate any help i can get on this.

```
<style>

</style>
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payments");

echo "<table border='0' align='center' text-align='left'>
<tr>
<th>Title:</th>
<th>Date:</th>
<th>Incoming:</th>
<th>Outgoing:</th>
<th>Notes:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

after adding code provided below:

```
<style>

</style>
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payments");

$totalIncoming = 0;
    $totalOutgoing = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $totalIncoming .= $row['incoming'];
      $totalOutgoing .= $row['outgoing'];
}
echo "<table border='0' align='center' text-align='left'>
<tr>
<th>Title:</th>
<th>Date:</th>
<th>Incoming:</th>
<th>Outgoing:</th>
<th>Notes:</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";

$profit = $totalIncoming - $totalOutgoing;
    echo "Profit :".$profit;


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

ok is this right?

```
<style>

</style>
<?php
include 'db-connect.php'; 

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM payments");

$totalIncoming = 0;
    $totalOutgoing = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $totalIncoming += $row['incoming'];
      $totalOutgoing += $row['outgoing'];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    $profit = $totalIncoming - $totalOutgoing;
    echo "Profit :".$profit;

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So before I suggest an answer.  Let me ask some questions.  Currently you don't have any ordering associated with your DB query at all.  This would seem very odd in this type of query in that you would likely want to guarantee the order of the results being returned. Do you actually need sorting?  Second, you mentioned being able to view totals by date.  Do you actually need some sort of date-based rollup of profit totals (i.e. weekly, monthly, etc.)?

Comment: Finally, is there some reason you chose to have incoming and outgoing payments amounts in two columns, rather than having one column that contains the amount and one column that indicates what type of transaction it is (i.e. incoming vs. outgoing)?

Comment: hi mike, i am building it the same way i do my books in excel. i need an incoming / out coming coloum to add which is an expense or money received. I currently just have it listed in date order in a never ending list. hope that answers your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$totalIncoming = 0;
    $totalOutgoing = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
      $totalIncoming += $row['incoming'];
      $totalOutgoing += $row['outgoing'];
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['incoming'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['outgoing'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['notes'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      }
    echo "</table>";
    $profit = $totalIncoming - $totalOutgoing;
    echo "Profit :".$profit;
```

Comment: hi pal, tryed adding this but getting an error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/stephen2/public_html/books/paymentsview.php on line 40

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket somewhere in your code most likely on the while loop

Comment: i think i have it in the right place but now its not loading the information for some reason? ill change the code above, tell me if ive done it totally wrong lol

Comment: You've done it wrong. In the first case, replace your code with my answer from the while loop till just before mysqli_close($con);

Comment: ok i have done that please check above ive updated the post with the code?

Comment: just to let you know it works now loading the items ect but dosnt add up the totals

Comment: it should work. this code works! Check in your database if your have integer values in the column incoming and outgoing

Comment: what are integer values?

Comment: ok its because i added a £ to the database input i think. is there a way i can now jget it to display as a currency?